# Joining a string and array elements not working

Tags: php, mysqli, concatenation

Here is my PHP code:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$statecodes = array(0=>"test1","test2");
while($i<sizeof($statecodes)) {
  $ini = "users_";
  $var = sprintf("%s%s", $ini, $statecodes[$i]);
  print $var;
  $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" . $var;
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  /* Execute the statement */
  $stmt->execute();
  $i=$i+1;
  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}
```

And the output i get is

```
users_
```

I want to create databases named **user_test1** and **user_test2**

Comment: You can just use `foreach` to loop over the array. Also, once you fix your variable, what will your query look like after PHP processes it? Will it be a valid query?

Comment: Im not sure but I think that this SQL query should work

Comment: It isnt working. I tried with $stmt = $conn->prepare("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo1");
/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. You were missing a space after `IF NOT EXISTS` and your loop was broken due to not initializing your counter. PHP provides a lot of convenient methods for doing things like array traversal and string concatenation; looking at your code I'd guess your experience is with a much lower level language? Things like `printf()` come in handy for some tasks, but it's overkill when you just want to jam two strings together!

Finally, no need to prepare and execute a query if it isn't a prepared statement with placeholders. You will, however, want to sanitize your input and check the result of your query for errors.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$statecodes = array("test1","test2");
foreach ($statecodes as $state) {
  $var = "users_$state";
  // remove dangerous characters!
  $var = preg_replace("/[^\w]/", "", $var);
  $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $var";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) {
      //do something!
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a spell. except the  $result = $mysqli->query($query); line. Please change it to  $result = $conn->query($query);

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it's fixed now